# Getting TypeError when the program tries to print get_close_matches

Tags: python, json, dictionary, difflib

I am developing a program which searches the meaning of words(word dictionary) and if I input a wrong spelling of the word, it corrects and suggests the correct word. However the program crashes after doing a similarity check.

data.json is the python dictionary file containing words as keys and their definitions as values.

Below is my code:

```
import json

from difflib import get_close_matches


data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def func(key):
    key= key.lower()
    if key in data:
        print(data[key])
    elif len(get_close_matches(key,data.keys())) > 0:
        ans = input("Did you mean %s instead?" % get_close_matches(key, data.keys())[0])
        if ans == "yes":
            print([data(get_close_matches(key, data.keys()))[0]])
        else:
            print("This word does not exist")

    else:
        print("This word does not exist")

key = input("Enter key:")

func(key)
```

Below is the output when I run the code:

```
Enter key:precipitattion
Did you mean precipitation instead?yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL-7450/PycharmProjects/Plural bo Minalowich/Test.py", line 24, in <module>
    func(key)
  File "C:/Users/DELL-7450/PycharmProjects/Plural bo Minalowich/Test.py", line 15, in func
    print([data(get_close_matches(key, data.keys()))[0]])
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, below is a similar code which works, not sure what Im missing:

> import json from difflib import get_close_matches
>
> data = json.load(open("data.json"))
>
> def translate(w):
>       w = w.lower()
>       if w in data:
>           return data[w]
>       elif len(get_close_matches(w, data.keys())) > 0:
>           yn = input("Did you mean %s instead? Enter Y if yes, or N if no: " % get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0])
>           if yn == "Y":
>               return data[get_close_matches(w, data.keys())[0]]
>           elif yn == "N":
>               return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it."
>           else:
>               return "We didn't understand your entry."
>       else:
>           return "The word doesn't exist. Please double check it."
>
> word = input("Enter word: ") translate(word)

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `print(data(get_close_matches(key, data.keys()))[0]])` you're trying to call data as if it were a function, but it is not

Comment: `data` is a dictionary, not a function. You are getting this error because by writing `print([data(...)])` is like trying to call a function named `data`. Try changing it to `print([data[...]])`.

Comment: Now I get the below:

Enter key:rainn
Did you mean rain instead?yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL-7450/PycharmProjects/Plural bo Minalowich/Test.py", line 24, in <module>
    func(key)
  File "C:/Users/DELL-7450/PycharmProjects/Plural bo Minalowich/Test.py", line 15, in func
    print([data[get_close_matches(key, data.keys())][0]])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Can you upload the code for `get_close_matches`? What does it return?